# How to get roles of current user in Fiori app?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-cloud-platform

I have a requirement to fetch all the roles declared on the SAP Cloud Platform. 
I am using below code to load the site service

```
try{
  jQuery.sap.require("sap.ushell.cpv2.services.cloudServices.SiteService");
}catch(oException){

}
```

but I am getting an exception:

```
"failed to load 'sap/ushell/cpv2/services/cloudServices/SiteService.js' from ../../resources/sap/ushell/cpv2/services/cloudServices/SiteService.js"
```

I have added the bootstrap code

```
script src="../resources/sap/ushell_abap/bootstrap/abap.js">script
```

but still cpv2 service is not availbable.

Is this CPV2 service depends upon the Launchpad version or HANA cloud version?
If not then how can I fix this error or is there any other way to fetch the roles?

Comment: When you log on to SAP Cloud Platform, do you see a menu item “Platform Roles” ?
There you will find by default the 5 predefined roles that are available on the SAP Cloud platform for subaccount members.
- Administrator
- Developer
- Support User
- Application User Admin
- Cloud Connector Admin

These roles are also mentioned here in this [blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/07/10/creating-custom-roles-on-sap-cloud-platform/) .

Are these the roles you are looking for?

Comment: No, Actually I am following this blog https://blogs.sap.com/2017/08/09/set-and-access-current-user-roles-fiori-launchpad-on-sap-cloud-platform-portal/ and I am getting the exception "not found" when loading the CPV2 services in component.js like this: jQuery.sap.require("sap.ushell.cpv2.services.cloudServices.SiteService")

Comment: Could you please post your component.js?
Could you please also post your file, where you added your bootstrap code script?

Comment: Issue resolved, it was due to asynchronous call of api

Comment: Can you explain how to solve it please ?

Comment: By following the step from this blog only :
https://blogs.sap.com/2017/08/09/set-and-access-current-user-roles-fiori-launchpad-on-sap-cloud-platform-portal/

Comment: our ui5 application should be published in FIORI portal and to check put a breakpoint at this line:
if (sap.ushell && sap.ushell.cpv2 && sap.ushell.cpv2.services && sap.ushell.cpv2.services.cloudServices && sap.ushell.cpv2.services.cloudServices.SiteService) {}

written in the controller and you will find this code will trigger twice and for the second time there will be some time gap so you will find the roles when this code triggered second time

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I believe the `SiteService` gives you *all* roles that are defined in Fiori Launchpad, not the ones assigned to the currentuser. So my answer here seems to be false.

You have to run the application inside an actual Fiori Launchpad (FLP), then the call to `jQuery.sap.require` should succeed.

The dependency `...sap/ushell_abap/bootstrap/abap.js` is not needed, as far as I know.

After successful requiring the module, you can use it as such:

```js
var oSiteService = sap.ushell.cpv2.services.cloudServices.SiteService(); // no `new`!
var oSiteServiceModel = oSiteService.siteModel;
var oAllData = oSiteServiceModel.getProperty("/");
```

For more information, you can go to
https://blogs.sap.com/2017/08/09/set-and-access-current-user-roles-fiori-launchpad-on-sap-cloud-platform-portal/